# Special characters and New line in php to JSON

Tags: php

I want to print a clean JSON response with all special characters displayed, paragraphs, line breaks etc.. I am using this function to perform all necessary operations and also clean up the response regarding bold text, etc.. basically, all I need is to do add a blank line in the response each time \r is detected in the text, for this specific JSON response. Is there a way to do it?

```
function retiraTagHTML($textoComTag){
     $textoComTag = html_entity_decode($textoComTag);
     $textoComTag = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "</p><p>", trim($textoComTag));
     $textoComTag = preg_replace('/\n/', '<br>',$textoComTag);
     return strip_tags($textoComTag, '<(.*?)>');
}
```

[image: JSON response showing some /r]

Comment: A newline can be either `CRLF` (`\r\n`), `LFCR` (`\n\r`), `LF` (`\r`) or `CR` (`\n`). You need to get *all* of these. Eg. through `(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)` instead of `\n`.

Comment: `'/\R+/'` will match all Unicode newline sequences

Comment: Is there a way to convert ALL html easily like html_entitiy_decode?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Which OS uses `\n\r`?

Comment: @Gumbo No current OS's, but [Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up doing what I needed

```
function removeHTMLtag($textWithTag){
    $textWithoutTag = strip_tags($textWithTag, '<(.*?)>');
    $textWithoutTag = html_entity_decode($textWithoutTag );
    return $textWithoutTag ;
}
```